# Как отключить вторую кнопку после клика на первую?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть 2 кнопки. После клика по первой в блок каждую секунду выводятся строки. При клике по второй - все строки из блока очищаются, и появляется строка "выключено". Как заблокировать вторую кнопку до момента пока все строки не загрузятся? Т.е. после нажатия на первую конопку на вторую можно будет нажать после загрузки всех строк. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Загрузки откуда?

Comment: Какие загрузки?

Comment: Вы сказали что выводяться строки в блок. Откуда и как?

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("buttonId").disabled=true;` - эта строка деактивирует кнопку.Она видна, но не работает.
`document.getElementById("buttonId").disabled=false;` -эта строка активирует кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ее прятать с помощь свойств Visible, либо свойства Disable. Через jQuery можно сделать.

```
 $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: мне надо не прятать, а менять внешность и отключать.
а вообще желательно пример  кода....

Comment: где задавать id кнопок?

Comment: @ArtemPro `<button id="тут твой id">Click Me!</button>`

Answer (score 0):

можно реализовать примерно так

```
var flag;
$("#but1").on("click", function () {
  flag=false;
  function(){
    //ваш код
    flag=true;
  }
  })
$("#but2").on("click", function () {
  if (flag===false){return false;}//тоесть вы не нажмете кнопку пока не выполнится код 1 кнопки
  //ваш код
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <button id="start" onmousedown="block();">Старт</button>
<div id="content"></div>
<button id="stop" onmousedown="alert('gg')">Стоп</button>
<script>
var button = document.getElementById('stop'),
content = document.getElementById('content'),
tempButton = button.getAttribute('onmousedown'),
    tempContent = content.innerHTML,
show = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (tempContent !== content.innerHTML && !!tempContent) {
            tempContent = content.innerHTML;
            show();
        } else {
            button.setAttribute('onmousedown',tempButton);
            //твой код(после анблока кнопки)
        }
    }, 1500);
},
block = function () {
    button.setAttribute('onmousedown','');
    //твой код(во время блока кнопки)
    show();
};
</script>
```